# how to set colour in jtextarea(java) to only some characters from the string, not to entire string?

Tags: string, jtextarea

How to set colour in jTextArea(java) some characters from the string, not to entire string?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't coded in Java in a while, but could you try creating a substring of the text you want to create a specific color, then set the color of the substring to the desired color.  I hope that makes sense.